# how to load a module that contains whitespace in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I want to load the module `C:\Users\ymelk\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\Works\Assignments\Functional Programming with Haskell\ex1` straight from GHCi but when i put

```
:l C:\Users\ymelk\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\Works\Assignments\Functional Programming with Haskell\ex1
```

ghci says `target C:\Users\ymelk\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer' is not a module name or a source file`

I suppose that this is because I have whitespaces.
one of the solution is to write the name of my documents like camelCase norm but this is too long (many documents)

Is there a way to load a module including whitespaces ?

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap it in quotes (`"`), like:

```
Prelude> :l "foo bar.hs"
```

You will need to escape the backslashes, so:

```
Prelude> :l "C:\\Users\\ymelk\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Computer Science\\Works\\Assignments\\Functional Programming with Haskell\\ex1"
```

That being said, filenames with spaces are often not a good idea, especially since a shell often sees spaces as an argument separator.

Comment: In the past, many programs failed when passed a path containing a space. Nowadays, this is less common, and those programs which still fail are generally regarded as buggy and fixed. The usual suspects are shell scripts, but even there it's often a matter of using `command "$X"` instead of `command $X`. Newly made scripts are generally written so to avoid this pitfall.